# Python libraries for MacOS

Tags: pyqgis-3, macos

In the win10 version of QGIS, you can install extra Python packages with pip commands directed at the QGIS python 3 environment. For example, I've got access to scikit-learn form my QGIS Python console.

What is the equivalent process for a mac?

The sticking point seems to be getting the terminal to point to QGIS's Python 3 environment. In Windows it's just a py3_env command. No luck on MacOS.

Comment: Have you tried to used the Python framework in the QGIS3.app ? `/Applications/QGIS3.14.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/python3`

Comment: No, issue is that I am trying to do this for my students that have a mac without having a mac myself. Is there a tutorial somewhere I could point to?